# Jenkins pipeline job reports Groovy binding error

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins job that loads a groovy file which defines the pipeline to run. When I run this job it reports an error - `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: â€‹ for class: groovy.lang.Binding` (stack trace below).

This was working yesterday and inexplicably stopped working.  I have searched the docs, googled the error and simplified the job and common groovy file as much as possible but cannot identify the issue so far.

**My question is, has anyone seen this issue before and if so what was the root casue and solution?**

*Pipeline job script:*

```
#!groovy

node
{
    def pipeline = load "CommonPipeline.groovy"
    pipeline.run()
}
```

*CommonPipeline.groovy:*

```
#!groovy
​
def run()
{
     echo "#### THIS WORKS! ####"
}

return this
```

*Stack Trace:*

```
Started by user jenkins
[Pipeline] node
Running on Worker in c:\path\to\script\groovy-test
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] load
[Pipeline] { (CommonPipeline.groovy)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // load
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: ​ for class: groovy.lang.Binding
    at groovy.lang.Binding.getVariable(Binding.java:63)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onGetProperty(SandboxInterceptor.java:224)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$4.call(Checker.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedGetProperty(Checker.java:238)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.getProperty(SandboxInvoker.java:28)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyAccessBlock.rawGet(PropertyAccessBlock.java:20)
    at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:2)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.get(PropertyishBlock.java:74)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.LValueBlock$GetAdapter.receive(LValueBlock.java:30)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.PropertyishBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(PropertyishBlock.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:58)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:154)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:33)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable$1.call(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.GroovySandbox.runInSandbox(GroovySandbox.java:108)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:30)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:324)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$100(CpsThreadGroup.java:78)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:236)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:224)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:63)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:112)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Silly mistake - the "shebang" header statement `#!groovy` is not required when your file extension is .groovy.  I removed this from `CommonPipeline.groovy` and now the job works. I did not think this would make any difference!

Oddly, I had not changed this since it stopped working yesterday. The only change I can think of were some Jenkins plugin updates I installed...

I will leave this question and solution in case someone else hits this issue.
​

Comment: I've been getting this issue but have no shebang. No idea why it's occurring.